# tkinter saving appearance changes

Tags: python, tkinter

How to make two buttons still appear after closing the program and calling the function causes the addition of further buttons?
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
def add_button():
   b2 = Button(win, text="click").grid()

b1 = Button(win, text="click", command=add_button).grid()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to save the number of buttons e.g. in a file on closing and read the file when launching the app to restore the GUI.

Comment: You could show it by example because I'm a beginner and I don't know how I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save/restore the appeareance, in your case you need to save the number of buttons. The basic idea is:

1. Read the config file containing the number of buttons and create them (see `restore_window()` in the code below).
2. Let the users add as many buttons as they want, keeping track of how many buttons were added (in the `number_of_btns` variable).
3. Save the number of buttons in a file when the window is closed. To do so I used `win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", save_and_close)` to execute `save_and_close()` when the user closes the window.

Here is the full code:

```
# from tkinter import * -> to be avoided because it may lead to naming conflicts
import tkinter as tk 

number_of_btns = 0  # keep track of the number of buttons

def restore_window():
    try: 
        with open("window_config.txt", "r") as file:  # open file
            nb = int(file.read())  # load button number
    except Exception:  # the file does not exist or does not contain a number
        nb = 0
    for i in range(nb):
        add_button()

def save_and_close():
    with open("window_config.txt", "w") as file:
        # write number of buttons in file
        file.write(str(number_of_btns))
    win.destroy()

def add_button():
    global number_of_btns  # change value of number_of_btns outside the scope of the function
    b2 = tk.Button(win, text="click").grid()
    number_of_btns += 1

win = tk.Tk()
win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", save_and_close)  # execute save_and_close when window is closed

b1 = tk.Button(win, text="Add", command=add_button).grid()
restore_window()    
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: how to make the newly created button have different text, command, location?

Comment: @marcin You can use a list of (text, command, location) for your buttons, even randomly choose inside the list if you want. If you need to save a more complicated GUI, you might want to use something more than just a text file, e.g. a config file using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/configparser.html?highlight=configparser#module-configparser) or save a dictionnary with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle). If you have more questions/issues while exploring these options, please ask new questions on SO.